# spring repository in query: passing a big list

Tags: java, spring-data

I want to know if it is considered correct / safe to pass a list of about 10000-20000 objects (f.e. Long or String) to an *IN query* by using a spring-data repository interface.

The class and method could look like this:

```
@Repository
public interface TransactionsRepository extends JpaRepository<TransactionsEntity, Long> {

    List<TransactionsEntity> findByCustomerIdIn(List<Long> customerIdList);
}
```

Maybe there is another way of doing such query more efficiently?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Optimise query times and performance

Comment: I meant what are you trying to do? Because I thought about loading the 10k - 20k objects into list and use stream Java 8 to filter

Comment: I cannot use java 8 on this project. I need to understand if it is safe to pass such a big list to an IN query by using spring repository interface.

Comment: @AlanHay multiple ins cannot be used because my list is dynamic. Meanwhile I have solved this by splitting up my list into smaller ones.

Comment: Which is one of the proposed solutions in the question linked to.

Comment: @AlanHay the popular proposal is to use a temp table and in my case I have no privileges to go with it. You could argue, but there is nothing said about jpa or spring data.

Comment: There is nothing special about JPA or Spring Data. If you're looking for performance, you have much bigger worries. Passing 20k elements in an IN clause doesn't even work.